# Different Rules to Handle duplicate values in Table

Tags: sql, sql-server

Duplicates in `Table 1` are indentifies as follows;

```
select quote_ref, count (*) 
from table 1 
group by quote_ref 
having count(*) > 1
```

Now I want the eliminate the duplicates based on the 2 rules below .

Take the entry that has the `Status= Complete` 
If none in complete status then take the one with `max([created_date ])`
Else Flag to look at ?

Suppose I need a `CASE` statement with a delete, but not sure how to construct ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For SQL Server 2005+, you can do the following:

```
;WITH CTE AS
(
    SELECT  *, 
            ROW_NUMBER() 
            OVER(PARTITION BY quote_ref 
                 ORDER BY CASE WHEN [Status]='COMPLETE' THEN 1 ELSE 2 END, 
                 created_date DESC) RowNum
    FROM table1
)
DELETE FROM CTE
WHERE RowNum != 1
```

In this case, I'm assuming that the row that you don't want to delete is the one with `status = 'COMPLETE'` or the one with the maximum `created_date`. If is the other way around, you can simply change the `WHERE` condition.